# object APIResponse[~_ReturnT] can't be used in 'await' expression , error in API using Supabase , FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, supabase

I have this service class in a FastAPI with Supabase API :

```
class JournalLawService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = create_supabase_client()

    async def get_journal_law_by_id(self, law_id: int) -> Optional[JournalLaw]:
        try:
            result = (
                await self.client.table("Law").select("*").eq("id", law_id).execute()
            )
            return result.get("data", [None])[0]
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error fetching journal law by ID {law_id}: {e}")
            return None
```

I got this error :

```
Error fetching journal law by ID 5000: object APIResponse[~_ReturnT] can't be used in 'await' expression
```

how can I fix this problem , is it related to supabase or to async/await logique?

I tried removing the -> Optional[JournalLaw]:
I tried returning the data as it is but didnt work
if you need any question concerning the table schema , folder structure I can answer